# When was Lord Ganpati Discovered?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, belief, ganesha

From what I know of...

A boon bestowed upon Lord Ganpati made mandatory that first `shloka`(verse) of any religious book should start with `shree ganeshaya namaha`.

But after reading `mahabharta` in its original form, its first verse starts with:

> नारायणं नमस्कृत्य नरं चैव नरॊत्तमम 
>  देवीं सरस्वतीं चैव ततॊ जयम
>   उदीरयेत
>
> nārāyaṇaṃ namaskṛtya naraṃ caiva narottamam 
>  devīṃ sarasvatīṃ caiva tato jayam udīrayet
>
> Bowing to Lord Nārāyaṇa (Kṛṣṇa), to Nara, the best of men [namely Arjuna],   and to the Goddess [of knowledge] Sarasvatī, then may one
>   commence the [lore called] Jaya (Victory).

This slightly amazed me!

How Lord Ganpati was unknown till time of `mahabharta`? That obviously means at time of `Ramayana` too, since it happened before `mahabharta`.

[Reference](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs01001.htm) For `Mahabharta`.

Comment: It is made mendetory that first shloka(verse) of any religious - I don't think that's true, he should be the first to be worshiped among all devas.

Comment: There are lots of references to Lord Ganapati is referenced in vedas.

Comment: Ganapati existed from the beginning of time. Different manifestations during different kalpas are detailed in different puranas.

Comment: I think generally we do wtite "Om Shree Ganeshayan Maha" seprately ,before starting to write any  text ,so this isn't part of any shloka's.So obviously the first verses of any text is different.Some prints  do write this & some do not.

Comment: You also have to consider the fact that it was **Ganapati** who **wrote down** that sloka when Vyasa spoke it.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what you mean by "discovered". Ganesha is mentioned in Vedas, as described in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/12043/3500). So, He is eternal and He manifests differently in different Kalpas.

*[Chapter 13](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-ii/chapter-13/topic-1) Rudra Samhita (Kumara Khanda) of Shiva Purana* says

> ब्रहोवाच 
>  कल्पभेदाद्गणेशस्य जनिः प्रोक्ता विधेः परात्। 
> शनिदृष्टं शिरश्छिन्नं सञ्चितं गाजमाननम्॥५॥
>
> Brahma said, “Because of the difference in the kalpas, there are
> several stories of the birth of Ganesa. Once, because of Saturn's
> casting his gaze over Ganesa, the latter's head was cut off and it was
> replaced with the head of an elephant.
>
> ड्दानी श्वेतकल्पोक्ता
> गणेशोत्पत्तिसच्यते। । 
>  यत्र छिन्नं शिरस्तस्य शिवेन च कृपालुना।। ६॥
>
> Presently, the story of the birth of Ganesa in the Sveta kalpa is
> being narrated, wherein, the compassionate Šiva, had himself cut off
> his head.

So, it's clear Ganesha is eternal (as He is mentioned in Vedas) and He manifests differently in different Kalpas. Each Purana describes stories of a particular kalpa which i discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11077/3500) and Shiva Purana discusses stories of Sveta kalpa.

Similarly, *[Chapter 23](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/the-varaha-purana/vol-i/chapter-23/topic-1) Part 1 of Varaha purana* mentions different birth story of Ganesha. Varaha Kalpa mentions mainly stories of "Manava Kalpa".

> 11-15. How is it not there in sky ?" So thinking he laughed. By the
> power of knowledge, by what was seen by Rudra in the sky, by what was
> said by Brahma formerly as the body of all beings, by the laughter of
> Rudra, by all these four in the four elements Earth and the rest,
> there arose a boy effulgent with glowing face, looking like Rudra
> himself and stupefying Devas with the charm of his dazzling
> brilliance.
>
> 16. Seeing the person of this great boy, Uma remained with eyes stuck on him.
> 17. Looking at the beautiful form of the boy and thinking of the fickleness of women's minds Rudra got angry and cursed him.
> 18. "O boy, you will attain an elephant's face, protruding belly and yajnopavlta of serpents".

Coming to Sweta Varaha Kalpa (Current Kalpa), we do not know exactly in which Mahayuga He was born.

Parvati was born just after beginning of Vaivasvara Manvantara in Swetha varaha Kalpa as mentioned in [this chapter](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/27478/62f_chapter_19_2.pdf) of Skanda Purana.  But Ganesha is [elder brother of Skanda](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10867/3500).  He might be born just after Marriage of Shiva and Parvati.

Ramayana happened during 24th treta yuga and Mahabharata happened during 28th Dwapara Yuga as mentioned in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7189/3500). There is huge difference in time span of Ganesha's birth and Mahabharata or Ramayana.

Moreover, it was Ganesha who wrote Mahabharata when Krishna Dwaipayana Vyasa narrated, as mentioned in [Adiparva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01002.htm) of Mahabharata.

So, Ganesha existed and well known even during times of Mahabharata and Ramayana.