# What was the age of Lord Ganesha when he wrote Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, ganesha

In which year was load Ganesha was born?

What was the age of Lord Ganesha when he wrote Mahabharata?

Comment: Gods do not write books, humans do. See [Why did BORI excise the Vyāsa-Gaṇeśa conversation from its critical edition of the Mahābhārata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20423/why-did-bori-excise-the-vy%c4%81sa-ga%e1%b9%87e%c5%9ba-conversation-from-its-critical-edition-of-t)