# Is there any mention of Ganesha in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, ganesha

Ganesha is a important hindu deity.

Is there any mention of Ganesha in the Vedas?

Comment: The Ganapati upanishad is attached to AthervaVeda. Also there is an [Ganapati suktam](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/gaNapatisUkta.html) in Rigveda.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Were Ganesh and Kartikeya mentioned in Vedas? Is Ganapati Elder to Kartikeya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8921/3500)

Comment: Vaishnavites claim to see Narasimha in Rig Veda.  Others claim Rama, krishna and so forth.  Given the elasticity of Sanskrit, I am sure Ganesa can be read into Rig Veda :-) @dark knight

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a refrence of Ganapathi in **Yajurveda 16:25**

> नमो **गणेभ्यो गणपति**भ्यश्च वो नमो नमो व्रातेभ्यो व्रातपतिभ्यश्च वो नमो नम्गृत्सेभ्यो गृत्सपतिभ्यश्च वो नमो नमो विरूपेभ्यो विश्वरूपेभ्यश्च वो नमः ॥२५॥

> 24. Homage to assemblies (ganas) and to you **ganapathi,** homage to horses and to you masters of horses, homage to you hosts that wound and pierce, to you destructive armies with excellent bands be homage.

**Rigveda 2:23:1**

> गणानां त्वा **गणपतिं** हवामहे कविं कवीनामुपमश्रवस्तमम् । ज्येष्ठराजं ब्रह्मणां ब्रह्मणस्पत आ नः शृण्वन्नूतिभिः सीद सादनम्॥१॥

> 1. WE call thee, **Ganapathi (Lord and Leader of the heavenly hosts),** the wise among the wise, the famousest of all, The King supreme of prayers, O Brahmanaspati: hear us with help; sit down in place of sacrifice.

**Rigveda 10:112:9**

> नि षु सीद **गणपते** गणेषु त्वामाहुर्विप्रतमं कवीनाम् । न ऋते त्वत्क्रियते किं चनारे महामर्कं मघवञ्चित्रमर्च॥९॥

> 9. **Lord of the hosts (Ganapathi),** amid our bands be seated: they call thee greatest Sage among the sages. Nothing is done, even far away, without thee: great, wondrous, Maghavan, is the HYMN I sing thee.

**Taittaraiya Samhita 4:5:4:1**

> नमो **गणेभ्यो गणपति**भ्येश्च भो नमो:|

> Salutations to him who is in (Gana) host and who is in **Ganapati** (Lord of host).

Ganesha is mentioned as *danti* the tusked god in Taittaraiya Aranyaka.

**Taittaraiya Aranyaka 10:1:5**

> तत्पुरुषाय विद्महे **वक्रतुन्डाय** धीमहि तन्नो **दन्ति** प्रचोदयात् ।

> We meditate upon Him who has a **curved trunk**. May the tusked one show us the right path.

**Taittaraiya Aranyaka 10:1:15**

> रुद्रो रुद्रश्च **दन्तिश्च** नन्दिः षण्मुख एव च ।

> गरुडो ब्रह्मा विष्णुश्च नारसिहंस्तथैव च ।।

> Rudra, **Danti**, Nandi, Shanmukha, Garuda, Brahma, Vishnu, Narsimha are the mentioned gods.

Comment: Can you give me English translation of these verses.