# Which direction should the chanter face while chanting ganesha slokas? Is there any directions mentioned specific in vedas/puranas for lord ganesha?

Tags: vedas, mantras, ganesha, stotra, ganapati

[Why is the mantra Gananam Tva Ganapatim used to worship Lord Ganesha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48202/why-is-the-mantra-gananam-tva-ganapatim-used-to-worship-lord-ganesha?newreg=c450b2852485490ea612fcca14244cd7)

In the above link, it is mentioned south, please clarify

Comment: "and meditate on him as seated facing the south, with a delightful face," in the above answer means that Lord Ganesha should face south.. it means that chanter would face north.. if chanter also faces south then it becomes Ganesha seeing our back...

Answer (score 1):

Usually while doing chanting of mantras/stotras one has to face either East or North. One must not face the other two directions.

Quoting from the book ["JAPA YOGA -- A COMPREHENSIVE TREATISE ON
MANTRA-SASTRA  by Sri Swami Sivananda"](http://japa-yoga.org/japa.pdf)

> The glory of the Name of God cannot be established through reasoning
> and intellect. It can certainly be experienced or realised, only
> through devotion, faith and constant repetition.  Japa is of three
> kinds, viz., Manasika Japa or mental Japa, Upamsu Japa or Japa with
> humming, and Vaikhari Japa or loud audible Japa.  Mental repetition or
> Japa or Manasika Japa is more powerful than loud Japa.  Get up at 4
> a.m., and do the Japa for two hours. Brahmamuhurta is most favourable
> for Japa and meditation.  If you cannot take bath, wash your hands,
> feet, face and body, and sit for Japa.  **Face the North or the East
> when sitting. This enhances the efficacy of the Japa.**  Sit on
> Kusa-grass or deer-skin or rug. Spread a sheet of cloth over it. This
> conserves body-electricity.  Do some prayer before starting the Japa.
> Have a steady pose. Have Asana-Japa or conquest over Asana. You must
> be able to sit on Padma, Siddha or Sukha Asana for three hours at a
> stretch.  When you repeat the Mantra, have the feeling or mental
> attitude that the Lord is seated in your heart, that Sattva or purity
> is flowing from the Lord to your mind, that the Mantra purifies your
> heart, destroys desires and cravings and evil thoughts. *(from page 53 of the PDF)*

The above instruction is said while talking about Nama Japa and so it is applicable for recital of Stotras or Slokas too. Also, it is generally applicable for all deities including Lord Ganesha.

When performing, what we call Shanti Karmas, like the usual Puja, Japa etc., one must face the East or the North only. Even for performing Achamana, which is performed at the beginning of any Hindu ritual, one has to face either East or North too.

> Manu Smriti 2.61. He who knows the sacred law and seeks purity shall
> always perform the rite of sipping with water neither hot nor frothy,
> with the (prescribed) tirtha, in a lonely place, **and turning to the
> east or to the north**

For performing Abhichara Karmas (Marana, Ucchatana, Vashikarana eyc.) one may need to face West or South but all for other usual rituals we must face only the East or North while performing them.